# $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}(A_n\cap B_n)=\Big(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} A_n\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} B_n\Big)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $\mathcal{A}=\{A_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ two collection of not empty sets. So is true that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}(A_n\cap B_n)=\Big(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} A_n\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} B_n\Big)$? Then if it is generally false, could it be true if $\mathcal{A}$ is a chain respect the inclusion and the sets of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: If $A_1 = B_2$ is disjoint from $A_2 = B_1$, then $(A_1 \cap B_1) \cup (A_2 \cap B_2) = \varnothing$ while $(A_1 \cup A_2) \cap (B_1 \cup B_2) = A_1 \cup A_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{2n}=\{0\}=B_{2n+1}$ and $A_{2n+1}=B_{2n}=\{1\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$; then

$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(A_n\cap B_n)=\varnothing\ne\{0,1\}=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\right)\;.$$

Now let $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k\le n\}$ and $B_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k>n\}$. Then

$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(A_n\cap B_n)=\varnothing\;,$$

and

$$\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\right)=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\ne\varnothing\;,$$

even though $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an increasing chain and $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ a decreasing chain with respect to $\subseteq$.

Comment: Okay, instead if $\mathcal{A}$ is a chain respect the inclusion and the sets of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint could the statement true?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You run into the same problem: let $B_n=\{n+1\}$ in my second example.

Comment: Okay, so the statement is generally false.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Yes, I think that any conditions making it true would have to be very restrictive.

Comment: Okay, so could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637147/if-f-ii-in-bbbn-is-a-collection-of-not-empty-closed-sets-mutually-disjo)? Indeed it seems that this equality could be true in a one particular case.