# If $\{F_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is a collection of not empty closed sets mutually disjoint in a continuum $X$ then $X\neq\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i$.

Tags: general-topology

What shown below is a reference from "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Cassarubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa

> **Lemma**
>
> If $X$ is a continuum that is covered by a sequence of numerable mutually disjoint closed sets $F_1,...,F_n$  of which at least two are not empty then for any $i\in\Bbb{N}$ there exist a continuum $C\subseteq X$ such that $C\cap F_i=\varnothing$ and at least two of the sets $C\cap F_1, C\cap F_2,...,C\cap F_n,...$ are not empty.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> If $\{F_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is a collection of not empty closed sets mutually disjoint in a continuum $X$ then $X\neq\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i$.
>
> *Proof*. So we suppose that the theorem if false. So $X=\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i$, where $\mathcal{F}=\{F_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$is a partition of $X$ that is composed of closed disjoint set of which at least two are not emtpy. Since $X$ is connected, the collection of the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ that are not empty is infinite. So without loss of generality we can suppose that any $F_i$ is not empty. So for the previous lemma there exist a continuum $C_1\subseteq X$ such that $C_1\cap F_1=\varnothing$ and at least two of the sets of the sequence $C_1\cap F_\, C_1\cap F_2,...$ are not empty. So the continuum $C_1$ is equal to $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}(C_1\cap F_i)$ and $C_1$ and $\{C_1\cap F_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ respect the condictions of the previous lemma and so there exist a conitnuum $C_2\subseteq C_1$ such that $C_2\cap(C_1\cap F_2)=C_2\cap C_2\cap F_2=\varnothing$ and at least two elements of the sequence $C_2\cap F_1, C_2\cap F_2$ are not empty. So in this way we cand make a sequence $C_1\supseteq C_2\supseteq...\supseteq C_n\supseteq....$ of continuum of $X$ such that $C_i\cap F_i=\varnothing$ for any $i\in\Bbb{N}$. So this means that 
>   $$
> \Big(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i\Big)=\varnothing
> $$
>   and so $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i=\varnothing$. However since $X$ is compact, it must be $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i\neq\varnothing$, that is impossible.

Here for sake of completeness the text of the original proof: I hope that my was a good traslation.

[image]

So I don't understand why $\Big(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i\Big)=\varnothing$. Indeed using induction it is possible to proof that $\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i\Big)=\varnothing$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ but I don't know if $\Big(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb{N}}F_i\Big)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\Big[\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\Big)\cap\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i\Big)\Big]=\varnothing$.  Moreover is it must br $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb{N}}C_i\neq\varnothing$ because the collection of $C_i$ is a collection of closed sets of $X$ that has the finite intersection property? 
Finally I don't understad why in the first part we prove that any $F_i$ is not empty if $X$ is connected: indeed for hypothesis $\{F_i:i\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is a collection of not empty closed sets.

So could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ you have

$$\left(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}C_i\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i\right)\subseteq\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nC_i\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i\right)=\varnothing\;,$$

so

$$\left(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}C_i\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}F_i\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(\left(\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}C_i\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i\right)\right)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\varnothing=\varnothing\;.$$

Comment: Okay, so finally what can you say about the observation I did about the first part of the proof?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: We only assume that at least two of the sets $F_i$ are non-empty. The first part of the proof points out that $X$ cannot be covered by a finite family of two or more pairwise disjoint connected sets, so if at least two of the $F_i$ are non-empty, infinitely many of them must be non-empty in order to cover $X$. But then we can simply throw away any empty ones and assume that all of the $F_i$ are non-empty: we’ll still have an infinite collection of them.

Comment: Okay, it is clear: however in the enunciation of the theorem it seems to me that we immediately suppose that any $F_i$ is not empty so what it is written in first part is pleonastic.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Good question; I didn’t notice that the statement of the theorem required all of the sets to be non-empty. My best guess is that the author wanted to give a reference for the result and therefore stated it more or less as Sierpiński had but was thinking in terms of the lemma when he wrote up the proof and didn’t notice that he was doing unnecessary work. Whatever the reason, it does look like an oversight on his part.

Comment: Okay, all clear. So thanks to much for your assistance!!! indeed I'm a self-taught so your explanation are very useful to me!!! so thanks again.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re very welcome; it can be tough when you’re working on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately in Italy this is necessary: italian teachers are damn listless and moreover they don't teach these things. They teach Calculus like they were born in XIX century, because they claim Topology is not necessary. Nevertheless, in my opinion mathematicians created it to make Calculus simpler and more intuitive, so I think everybody should study Set Theory and Topology. Indeed, I'm studing engineering and to study Fluid Dynamics I have to learn Differential Geometry and so even Topology and Set Theory. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in \bigcap C_i\cap\bigcup F_i$, then $x\in F_i$ for some $i$. For this (as for any) $i$, also $x\in C_i$, but $C_i\cap F_i=\emptyset$.